# Syntax error, unexpected T_IF in my script

Tags: php, syntax, fopen, fwrite

im new in PHP, make a script, and get this problem:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/name/data/www/mellowkids/report.php on line 49

```
<?php
//получение переменных отправленных в запросе
$offer_id = $_REQUEST['offer_id'];
$offer_name = $_REQUEST['offer_name'];
$postback_id = $_REQUEST['wp_id'];
$postback_name = $_REQUEST['wp_name'];
$site = $_REQUEST['site'];
$subaccount = $_REQUEST['subaccount'];
$action_type = $_REQUEST['action_type'];
$target_id = $_REQUEST['target_id'];
$target_name = $_REQUEST['target_name'];
$payout = $_REQUEST['payout'];
$click_id = $_REQUEST['click_id'];
$click_time = $_REQUEST['click_time'];
$event_time = $_REQUEST['event_time'];
$conversion_time = $_REQUEST['conversion_time'];
$ip = $_REQUEST['ip'];
$country = $_REQUEST['country'];
$city = $_REQUEST['city'];
$user_browser = $_REQUEST['user_browser'];
$user_os = $_REQUEST['user_os'];
$user_device = $_REQUEST['user_device'];
$cpl_id = $_REQUEST['cpl_id'];

//формируем строку лога
$line = 'Оффер: ' . $offer_name . 
'; ID Офера: ' . $offer_id . 
'; Postback ID: ' . $wp_id . 
'; Postback Name: ' . $wp_name . 
'; Источник перехода: ' . $site . 
'; Субаккаунт: ' . $subaccount . 
'; Тип действия: ' . $action_type . 
'; ID цели: ' . $target_id . 
'; Имя цели: ' . $target_name . 
'; Сумма выплаты: ' . $payout . 
'; ID клика: ' . $click_id . 
'; Время клика: ' . $click_time . 
'; Время действия: ' . $event_time . 
'; Время конверсии: ' . $conversion_time . 
'; IP адрес: ' . $ip . 
'; Страна: ' . $country . 
'; Город: ' . $city . 
'; Браузер: ' . $user_browser .
'; Операционная система: ' . $user_os .
'; Устройство: ' . $user_os .
'; ID действия: ' . $cpl_id .

//открываем файл для логгирования запросов
if ($handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/conversion_postback.log', 'a')) {
    fwrite($handle, '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ']:' . $line . "\n");
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

What need to fix this problem? Help me pls someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code Works:

```
<?php
//получение переменных отправленных в запросе
$offer_id = $_REQUEST['offer_id'];
$offer_name = $_REQUEST['offer_name'];
$postback_id = $_REQUEST['wp_id'];
$postback_name = $_REQUEST['wp_name'];
$site = $_REQUEST['site'];
$subaccount = $_REQUEST['subaccount'];
$action_type = $_REQUEST['action_type'];
$target_id = $_REQUEST['target_id'];
$target_name = $_REQUEST['target_name'];
$payout = $_REQUEST['payout'];
$click_id = $_REQUEST['click_id'];
$click_time = $_REQUEST['click_time'];
$event_time = $_REQUEST['event_time'];
$conversion_time = $_REQUEST['conversion_time'];
$ip = $_REQUEST['ip'];
$country = $_REQUEST['country'];
$city = $_REQUEST['city'];
$user_browser = $_REQUEST['user_browser'];
$user_os = $_REQUEST['user_os'];
$user_device = $_REQUEST['user_device'];
$cpl_id = $_REQUEST['cpl_id'];

//формируем строку лога
$line = 'Оффер: ' . $offer_name . 
'; ID Офера: ' . $offer_id . 
'; Postback ID: ' . $wp_id . 
'; Postback Name: ' . $wp_name . 
'; Источник перехода: ' . $site . 
'; Субаккаунт: ' . $subaccount . 
'; Тип действия: ' . $action_type . 
'; ID цели: ' . $target_id . 
'; Имя цели: ' . $target_name . 
'; Сумма выплаты: ' . $payout . 
'; ID клика: ' . $click_id . 
'; Время клика: ' . $click_time . 
'; Время действия: ' . $event_time . 
'; Время конверсии: ' . $conversion_time . 
'; IP адрес: ' . $ip . 
'; Страна: ' . $country . 
'; Город: ' . $city . 
'; Браузер: ' . $user_browser .
'; Операционная система: ' . $user_os .
'; Устройство: ' . $user_os .
'; ID действия: ' . $cpl_id; // the error was here

//открываем файл для логгирования запросов
if ($handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/conversion_postback.log', 'a')) {
    fwrite($handle, '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ']:' . "$line" . "\n");
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: new error PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/sweetopium/data/www/mellowkidsru/report.php on line 50 -

Comment: I've update the answer, try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
'; ID действия: ' . $cpl_id .
```

to

```
'; ID действия: ' . $cpl_id;
```

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/sweetopium/data/www/mellowkids.ru/report.php on line 50 - now this error

Comment: I don't see anything that would create that in the `fwrite` line

Answer (score 1):

You didn't terminate your string properly:

```
$line = 'Оффер: ' . $offer_name . 
'; ID Офера: ' . $offer_id . 
'; Postback ID: ' . $wp_id . 
'; Postback Name: ' . $wp_name . 
'; Источник перехода: ' . $site . 
'; Субаккаунт: ' . $subaccount . 
'; Тип действия: ' . $action_type . 
'; ID цели: ' . $target_id . 
'; Имя цели: ' . $target_name . 
'; Сумма выплаты: ' . $payout . 
'; ID клика: ' . $click_id . 
'; Время клика: ' . $click_time . 
'; Время действия: ' . $event_time . 
'; Время конверсии: ' . $conversion_time . 
'; IP адрес: ' . $ip . 
'; Страна: ' . $country . 
'; Город: ' . $city . 
'; Браузер: ' . $user_browser .
'; Операционная система: ' . $user_os .
'; Устройство: ' . $user_os .
'; ID действия: ' . $cpl_id; // <-- This is how it should be
```